# ValidateOnStart() and [Required] don't seem to work

Tags: c#, data-annotations, ioptions

I have an `appsettings.json` with the following contents:

```json
{
    "Settings": {
        "Greeting":  "Hello World"
    }
}
```

that I associate with

```cs
public sealed class SettingsOptions
{
    public const string SECTION = "Settings";

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    public string Greeting { get; init; } = default!;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    [Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2} inclusive.")]
    public int Age { get; init; }
}
```

Note: I intentionally removed `Age` in `appsettings.json` to simulate an invalid case.

I expect my **console** app below throws an exception but apparently it does not when the app starts.

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);
services.AddOptions<SettingsOptions>()
        .BindConfiguration(SettingsOptions.SECTION)
        .ValidateDataAnnotations()
        .ValidateOnStart();


var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

#if false // only for simulation
var settings = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<SettingsOptions>>().Value;
Console.WriteLine($"greeting: {settings.Greeting}, age: {settings.Age}.");
#endif

Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.ReadKey();

public sealed class SettingsOptions
{
    public const string SECTION = "Settings";

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    public string Greeting { get; init; } = default!;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    [Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2} inclusive.")]
    public int Age { get; init; }
}
```

It **does** throw an exception if I enable

```cs
#if true// only for simulation
var settings = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<SettingsOptions>>().Value;
Console.WriteLine($"greeting: {settings.Greeting}, age: {settings.Age}.");
#endif
```

I have two questions:

- Why doesn't `ValidateOnStart()` throw an exception before other parts need to resolve `SettingsOptions`?
- Why doesn't `[Required]` have any effect (it does not throw an exception when `Age` in `appsettings.json` is missing but instead it is set to its default value `0`)?

#### Edit:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="8.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations" Version="8.0.0" />
```

Comment: whic version of .net is this in ?

Comment: I think that you need IHost for that to work. Did you try it in Web Api or maybe implement  generic host in console app ?

Comment: ok , i was suggesting that validate on start maybe only works with IHost.

Comment: Ok so Required doesnt fire because int Attributes just get the default value of 0. Thats pretty normal. But it is weird that Range doesnt fire

Comment: `Range` **does** works. Only `Required` seems to be ignored or a useless attribute.

Comment: @user23207089 no what I meant is that I was suprised that it didnt fire when you expected it to. Im aware that it does fire later on

Comment: Note: `Range` gets fired only when `SettingsOptions` is manually resolved. `Range` does not get fired by `ValidateOnStart()`. `Required` never gets fired for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work inside the console app unless you implement the generic host in the console app. `ValidateOnStart` method is adding `ValidationHostedService` which is `IHostedService` which is triggered on `host.Run()`.